# Как расширить pom.xml в maven, в одном и тот же jar

Tags: maven

Меня интересует, как можно расширить pom.xml в одном и том же jar.
У меня pom.xml стал очень большой, мне еще нужно добавить очень много конфигураций для плагина jaxb, в pom.xml, для запуска генерации классов на основе xsd.

Я хотел бы перенести настройки этих конфигураций в этом же проекте, в дочерний pom.xml И этот дочерний pom.xml импортировать в родительский.

Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете разбить свой проект на несколько модулей либо вынести настройки в отдельный файл как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774727/how-to-minimize-maven-pom-xml)

Comment: Исключено, проект не должен разбиваться на модули...

Comment: Ну тогда может подойдёт второй вариант